# Trouble sanitizing form with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation, mysqli

Hello i was hoping could share light. I believe am make progress so far. i have a registration here:

What i wanted to do is sanitized my data before sending it database.

```
    <?php


    session_start(); 
    if(is_file('include/connection.php'))
    include_once('include/connection.php');
    else
    exit('Database FILES MISSING:(');


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $errors = array();
       $data = array();
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
        $user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];  
     // $created_at = $_POST['created_at'];
        $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);    

      //$created_at = date('Y-m-d');
        if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name, last_name, user_name, user_type, email, password) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"))){
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ")" . $mysqli->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $last_name, $user_name, $user_type, $email, $password_hash)){
         echo "Binding paramaters failed:(" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->execute()){
         echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno .")" . $stmt->error;
        }

        if($stmt) {
            $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Successfully registered, login here!";
            header('Location: index.php');

        }
        else{
            echo "Registration failed";
        }

    }

    $mysqli->close();

    ?>
```

> Execute failed: (1048)Column 'name' cannot be null

Above is the error am getting when I submit the data.

Have tried using `mysqli_real_escape_string` AND `mysqli->real_escape_string`

Can some advice if i still need to satinized even tho have bind the data.

---

Also in my database i have created_at field. see below code.

```
        $created_at = $_POST['created_at'];
        $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);    

      $created_at = date('Y-m-d');
        if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name, last_name, user_name, user_type, email, password, created_at) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"))){
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ")" . $mysqli->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $last_name, $user_name, $user_type, $email, $password_hash, $created_at)){
         echo "Binding paramaters failed:(" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
        }
```

Am getting this error:

> Prepare failed: (1136)Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/olami560/public_html/project/allocation/progress/register.php on line 30

Your help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: You have 6 questionmarks but 7 values to insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue #1, `mysqli_real_escape_string` requires a connection link when used procedurally. You don't need to escape when binding. If you were to escape it would be:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['name']);
```

or

```
$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

Issue #2, you have 7 columns listed and 7 values trying to be written but only have 6 placeholders and 6 string types.

So update to:

```
 if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name, last_name, user_name, user_type, email, password, created_at) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))){
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ")" . $mysqli->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $name, $last_name, $user_name, $user_type, $email, $password_hash, $created_at)){
         echo "Binding paramaters failed:(" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
        }
```

Note the number of `?`s, those are placeholders, and the number of `s`s in the `bind_param`. If the missing value is an integer, not a string change the last `s` to an `i` or whatever data type it is.

Comment: hi chris85, sorry for the reply... that works perfectly for me, it was my mistake. you did mention that while am using procedural i don't need to escape, does it leave me variable or ??

Comment: No, the driver handles escaping and quoting. You shouldn't escape.

Comment: oh brilliant. thanks for your contribution. i wanted to ask a big favor. i don't if no body mind. although have used stmt procedural... but in my login page i kind stuck on how i go about making the code prepared just have done in register page.

Comment: oh the code is too large for the comment. do i need to open a new question?

Comment: It should be the same process you used here. Anywhere input is going to SQL it should be a placeholder. The driver handles the insertion into the query, quoting, and escaping.

Comment: Of cause i did figure that out. Because am using user role based system for the first time, is a bit trick for me... but i will work on it myelf and see what i come up with. Thanks @chirs85

Comment: Okay, if you run into issues with it post a new question on that. Include code and error again. Please mark this as accepted if this resolves this queston.